# How valuable is studying cognitive psychology for UX?

Tags: psychology, education, learning, training

I am starting my second year in grad school and thinking about what to study. One thing that I know is good to have a grasp of is cognitive psychology. But I would like to get someones perspective.

Have you studied cognitive psychology? Either 1 class or more... and what did that give you?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I reckon you could skip cognitive psychology and still be good at UX. Some people have the right mindset within them. However, a lot don't and an understanding of how the brain processes information, how attention and memory work and what kind of things interrup them I would say will give you a great foundation to build on. A lot of UX is about empathising with users in different situations and good understanding of psychology will provide that.

I found my study of cognitive and applied psychology gives me insight into user behaviour and interface design issues which I wouldn't have had if I didn't.

The bottom line is I love UX because I love understanding how people work and how to provide interfaces which help them be more productive and less error prone. If you want to learn more about how people process information and how the mind works study cognitive psychology. If you're interest in UX is because of something else, don't.

Comment: Did you take a couple courses or do you have a degree in Cognitive Psych?

Comment: Totally agree! But i think that cog psychology it's more suitable for kinds like usability or accessibility than UX in general. I'm a cog psy graduated btw ;)

Comment: any books to recommend?

Answer (score 15):

I got my PhD in cognitive psychology, then researched and taught it (lecturer/assistant prof) for the last nine years before deciding to move into UX. You don't have to go my route ;o) but I'd say that it's a really useful subject in which to get a little experience, mainly for the following three reasons:

1. Being able to explain to your UX team the science behind why something doesn't work. This is incredibly useful, because it allows them to generalise the point and in doing so, learn from it. Example: in prototype testing, the user enters some data in a text field, presses OK to commit the change, and the screen reverts to an earlier page. The user's change is now registered peripherally on the screen, but because the whole page has changed, they don't notice it's there. Why? [Change blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_blindness). Knowing some of the basics of perception and attention means you can educate your UX team about why some things happen the way they do in testing, and it also gives them a vocabulary in which to frame the issue when it next comes up (and, ideally, avoid making the same mistake again).
2. Participant-based research skills. It's pretty hard to get through a course in cognitive psychology without having to design and run at least a couple of experiments. This is great practice for later on when you may have to deal with participants: you get a grounding in explaining to people what is going on, practice at observing human behaviour in a lab-based setting, and you have to consider the ethics of participation in studies.
3. Theoretical research skills. If you study nearly any flavour of academic psychology, you'll need to get used to reading and interpreting the experimental literature. This is a great skill to acquire, because it allows you to run off to, and interrogate, the literature whenever you want to understand a topic in more depth. It's really useful to get a feel for the relationship between psychological theory and human behaviour.

Comment: +1 already for "Being able to explain to your UX team the science behind why something doesn't work." I'm not sure if CogPsy 101 *is* the best for UX designers - but it should beat nothing.

Comment: I have been studying a lot since I asked this question and have been learning more about Cognitive Psychology. I use these principles all the time and it helps me to educate both clients and people around me. It also gives me a solid place to start looking and thinking about design problems. Thanks for a great answer. The last two though can also be acquired in other academic settings, especially the last one. The second point is something I have had much experience and education in doing my MS and taking usablity testing classes. Those were taught by someone with a PhD in cogn psych :)

Comment: I'm really glad it's working out for you :) And yeah, absolutely, (2) and (3) can be acquired in many academic settings. I wish I'd had the opportunity to do usability testing while I was a student! If only I'd known what it was  at the time … ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have a degree in informatics and really miss some basic knowledge about cognitive psychology. I read a lot at the moment to catch up on that.

It's not like there is some specific task in my UX work which I couldn't do without it (I do requirements research, ui concepts and usability tests). It's just the feeling that it would improve my interviewing skills (for research and tests) and help inform design decisions, if maybe only at a level that is hard to explain.

Answer (score 3):

*Have you studied cognitive psychology? Either 1 class or more..*.

Yes.

*and what did that give you?*

That's a difficult question.

***A lot of the academic cognitive psychology probably isn't that relevant to UX to be honest...*** (for example the language generation / comprehension bit )

Without some good guidance you could spend a lot of time reading psychology stuff, which, while interesting isn't really that relevant to UX.

Which begs the next question...

Answer (score 3):

Insights into cognitive (and social) psychology can be extremely useful (I did a 4 year degree in Applied Psychology, focusing on Human Computer Interaction), but as Damian Rees points out above - only study it if you are genuinely interested in it. You could certainly get by in UX without a background in cognitive psychology (many practitioners do, so it obviously isn't a pre-requisite). For me, working in the field of UX is the perfect mix - I love psychology and I love designing web and user interfaces so it gives me the opportunity to combine both. There's no reason why you can't stay informed about some of the issues by following popular psychology blogs (I'll post some links shortly ...) or even taking a look at something like http://www.getmentalnotes.com/ to get you started - actually, the resources section of the getmentalnotes site includes some good links to books and online reading/blogs: http://getmentalnotes.com/resources.

Why not take a look at some of these resources and see if they interest you?

Comment: Wow! I want those Mental Note cards now :D

Comment: They are quite cool Jeroen (I am in no way affiliated to them btw!) - I flicked through them for the first time the other day in the middle of a sketching session. About half a dozen cards were relevant to the project we were working on which helped promote some discussion and sketching amongst the team, and some interesting ideas we may not have otherwise arrived at.

Comment: It took me while to find his 'demo' deck though... 

http://getmentalnotes.com/assets/Mental-Notes-sneak-preview.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I studied 'Cognitive Systems' at the University of British Columbia, which covered: Programming/Informatics, Cognitive Psychology, Linguistics, and Philosophy.

While the Cognitive Psychology courses were somewhat useful for UX design, I found that the Linguistics courses were just as useful and provided a very different perspective. Discussions of how people communicate and perceive symbols, and hearing about different human languages demonstrated the variety of ways people think and process information. I also found similar insights in the Anthropology courses I took on the side. In general, psychology courses might be useful to you but so might other courses that explore communication, culture and interaction.

Of course, different universities/colleges mean different things by 'Linguistics' and 'Cognitive Psychology', so make sure to dig a bit before committing to something!

Comment: I also had the opportunity to go through a class, not in linguistics, but it was called a Communication Primer course and it focused heavily on how meaning is created with the use of words. It was very helpful to understand some of the nuances and have a clue on how to communicate 'meaning' with the language that I learnt.

Answer (score 1):

Designers/Architects can benefit by learning more about how people process, learn, remember information and understanding internal mental states.
Because Cognitive Psychology is all about internal mental states and process, where the user get bored, perception etc.
One simple answer to the question of "How valuable is studying cognitive psychology for UX,HCI?" is that there is already
agreement about the importance of both topics to
computer science education in general.  For example,
the report of the ACM/IEEE-CS Joint Curriculum Task
Force [2] clearly identifies human-computer
communication as one of the nine core areas of
computer science.  In this core topic the report authors
include both computer graphics and human-computer
interaction as related topics.  Furthermore, the authors
of the report point out that cognitive psychology is an
important supporting discipline for three of the nine
core areas of computer science, including artificial
intelligence and human-computer communication.

[Human-Computer Interaction and Cognitive Psychology in Visualization
Education.](http://old.siggraph.org/education/conferences/GVE99/papers/GVE99.T.Hewett.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of great answers here.

I'll just coin in that as someone with Cog Psy degree, I have recently reunited with my uni classmates, and we were catching up, and they asked if I use any of the knowledge from my degree for my work and that's when I realized I use it all the time, daily.

What is useful the most for me are two things: neuroscience and neurophysiology and the basic psychology of human activity, motivation, backgrounds, emotions, models of mind and so on.

This all is giving me an intuitive picture of how the mind, both individual and social, works, and as other people said, it is easy for me to formalize it, put it in words and communicate to my teams and my clients.

It also gives me an opportunity to see the user needs of the application from the deeper perspective, and often I can contribute to and enhance the business strategy and brand communication with ideas why the app should or shouldn't work and be positioned a certain way.

And it's tremendously helpful in running teams and keeping the team in balance — I see the social dynamics and I can act on them faster than anybody else, for example, let people blow off steam instead of going into the interpersonal conflict, or see which stakeholders don't trust each other, and fix their communication. 
Obviously, this is not UX per se, but as a Senior UX who grew to be a Product Manager, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be useful, but ultimately, no amount of 'expert' knowledge will help a UX person nearly as much as knowing how to properly perform a usability test.

There seems an assumption that UX issues are something solved by just having talented, skilled designers. It helps, but it's not the whole story. A study of UX principles and ideas will only help you eliminate the most obvious problems - removing them all means *sitting down with your users and watching how they actually use your software*. And that's why knowing how to conduct, organize and accurately interpret user feedback is the biggest weapon in your arsenal.